# Haskell label a binary tree through depth-first in-order traversal

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-search-tree

I need to label a binary tree through depth-first in-order traversal and I figured therefore I'd need to first go through the left branches of the tree and label those, then do the same for the right branches. My binary tree only stores values at the internal nodes (not at end nodes / leaves):

```
label :: MonadState m Int => Tree a -> m (Tree (Int, a))
label (Branch l x r) = do n <- get
                          l' <- label l
                          r' <- label r
                          return (Branch l' (n, x) r')
label (Leaf) = return Leaf
```

*EDIT: Need to use the State Monad however I'm not really grasping the usage of it. My current code is shown above but is not working properly.

EDIT: The desired result e.g. for:

```
Branch (Branch Leaf (-2) Leaf) 1 Leaf
```

should be:

```
Branch (Branch Leaf (0,-2) Leaf) (1,1) Leaf
```

Also I'm not sure how I should use the State Monad for it, I'm still quite confused for its use:

```
instance Monad (State' s) where

    -- return :: a -> State' s a
    return x = State' (\(s,c) -> (x, s, (c <> oneReturn) ))

    -- (>>=) :: State' s a -> (a -> State' s b) -> State' s b
    st >>= k = State' $ \(s,c) -> let (a, s', c') = runState' st (s,c)
                                  in runState' (k a) (s',(c' <> oneBind) )

instance MonadState (State' s) s where

    -- get :: State' s s
    get = State' $ \(s,c) -> (s,s, (c <> oneGet))

    -- put :: s -> State' s ()
    put s = State' $ \(_,c) -> ((),s, (c <> onePut))
```

Comment: You edited version looks fine except that it only reads the state but doesn't update it with an incremented value, so all your branches end up with the same label.

Comment: What is this `Tree` type? Do you desire an inorder or postorder traversal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need label_l, label_r functions. You don't need monads.
(You can use this example for learning about the state monad, but you don't have to.)

Just use (the standard trick of) enriching the specification from

```
Tree a -> Tree (Int, a)
```

to

```
f :: Int -> Tree a -> ( Tree (Int, a), Int )
```

the function gets the start label (first argument) and returns the labelled tree and the next label to use (in the second component of the result).

E.g.,

```
f 8 (Branch (Branch Leaf (-2) Leaf) 1 Leaf)
   == ( Branch (Branch Leaf (8,-2) Leaf) (9,1) Leaf), 10 )
```

This can be implemented easily, without any advanced concepts.

```
f s0 t = case t of
     Branch l k r -> let (l', s1) = f s0 l
                         (r', s2) = f s1 r
                     in  ...
```

With the state monad, your program would do exactly the same thing
(the "next label" is the state), but the notation is different,
which may or may not be beneficial (for learning/understanding).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just noticed I need to do this with the state monad indeed, I edited my post with a try on it (code's not working though) using the State Monad, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong though? Btw your example seems to make sense to me, but I'm not sure how I'd convert it to using the State Monad for the same purpose.

Comment: in addition to the hints given in other comments, see also the example at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#g:8

Comment: Thanks! I got it figured out now, I needed to start counting from the ends of the left branch.

Answer (score 17):

I'm afraid that your problem is easier to solve than the answers so far have suggested, if only you see how to take advantage of the structure you identify when you make your type definitions. Here's how it goes.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable, FlexibleContexts #-}

module LBT where

import Control.Monad.State

data Tree x
  = Leaf
  | Branch (Tree x) x (Tree x)
  deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

That much makes the `traverse` operation work left-to-right, i.e. in order, as you require.

Now explain what to do with a single element.

```
next :: MonadState Int m => m Int
next = do x <- get ; modify (+ 1) ; return x

labelElt :: MonadState Int m => x -> m (Int, x)
labelElt x = (,) <$> next <*> pure x
```

The `next` operation gives you the next value and updates the counter. The `labelElt` operation then decorates a single value with its counter. And now

```
label :: MonadState Int m => Tree x -> m (Tree (Int, x))
label = traverse labelElt
```

you get the program you already paid for when you defined your type. When you know what to do with one element, you can manage a whole structure. For free. No ad hoc recursion is needed here! The structure of your type delivers the structure of your program. Haskell will do that for you if only you let it.

Comment: Yep, let Haskell do that for you: `label :: Traversable t => t a -> t (Int, a); label = snd . mapAccumL (\i x -> (i + 1, (i, x))) 0`.

Comment: As a follow up, what other structures for a tree would yield different traversal orders? I suppose that moving the node before and after the trees would yield pre-order and post-order, respectively. Are there any other interesting choices?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Well, I doubt we'll shake *breadth-first* traversal out of `DeriveTraverse` anytime soon...

Answer (score 1):

One way to structure your function with the State monad is:

```
label :: MonadState m Int => Tree a -> m (Tree (Int, a))
label t = do
    -- Fetch the next label number from the state monad with "get".
    -- Increase the label number by one and store it back in the state with "put".
    -- Pattern match on "t" and call "label" recursively.
```

I'm assuming you're already familiar with `do`-syntax? Try to write the above function and then update the question with your new code if you need more hints.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I'm not sure how I'd get the label number with the state monad's get function? Wouldn't that return a new function with a state and counter parameter instead of a number? Also I need to return a value of type m (Tree (int, a), how'd I do this by the method you described?

Comment: You should probably start by reading the [Fistful of Monads](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads) chapter from LYAH to get a basic grasp of how to use monadic functions in a do-block followed by [For a few monads more](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more) which covers the state monad specifically (among a few others).

Comment: Well I do know how to use monadic functions in a do-block however I don't grasp the usage of the State Monad, but I'll check For a few monads more as you mentioned for that.