# Labeling a tree depth-first in-order in haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, label

I basicly have the same question as asked here: [Haskell label a binary tree through depht-first in-order traversel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26401264/5355979) but the answer there was never actually given and I can't comment there due to lack of reputation.

Right now i have a function `label`:

```
label :: MonadState m Int => Tree a -> m (Tree (Int, a))
label Leaf = return Leaf
label (Branch leftTree a rightTree) = do n <- get
                                         modify (+1)      
                                         l' <- label leftTree
                                         r' <- label rightTree
                                         return (Branch l' (n,a) r')
```

where `Tree a = Leaf | Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a)`.

Now this labels the tree breadth-first. Now I want to label the `leftTree` first, then the `Branch` itself and then the `rightTree`, but I don't see how to achieve this and the other thread doesn't help me further.

Comment: Hint: what does `n <- get` do? Does it matter which line it goes on?

Comment: Thank you, that was all I needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered the older question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33191820/828361). Sorry for mistakenly attributing to to you. The point is that when you wrote your type, you also told Haskell how to `traverse` your data structure in a way that ensures the `get` happens in the middle.

The program that you locally wrote incorrectly yourself is a program you already wrote correctly just by defining your type, had you only known.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, it wasn't MY question, I just had the same question. Very interesting read on your solution and very elegant use of some of haskell's properties.